# Why won't tezos-client find my Ledger Nano S?

Tags: node, ledger

I'm setting up a Linux Tezos baking node with Ledger Nano S. The node is running and synced, but `list connected ledgers` will not show that the Ledger is connected.

Both the wallet and baking apps are installed from Ledger Live. The firmware on the Nano S is the newest.

Linux shows the USB with `lsusb`, and `dmesg` shows all the details of the Ledger, but `list connected ledgers` finds no Nano S.

I have modified my udev rules to include the correct group for my user account.

But the Tezos client still doesn't detect the Ledger Nano S.

Comment: Are you running either the wallet or baker app on the ledger when you try to connect (asking because you don't specify this, only that you have both apps installed).

Comment: Perhaps you could share the contents of /etc/udev/rules.d/20-hw1.rules and the output of the `id` command so we can have a look.

Comment: Please show the output of ls -la /dev/bus/usb/*/* and also provide the username you try to connect with and the groups of this user.

Comment: Found a solution that worked for me. "Option 1" on this [Ledger Support Page](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005165269-Fix-connection-issues).

Comment: same problem only on root see ledger

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, you need to add the user to the `root` group.

For the `rich` user, the command is:

```
sudo adduser rich root
```

Logout and back in for the change to take affect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Linux (debian 11). To solve the issue, I set the owner of my ledger to be my current user by adapting the udev rules.

Here is the adapted udev rules for the user `tezos` for the Nano S:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2c97", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001|1000|1001|1002|1003|1004|1005|1006|1007|1008|1009|100a|100b|100c|100d|100e|100f|1010|1011|1012|1013|1014|1015|1016|1017|1018|1019|101a|101b|101c|101d|101e|101f", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl", OWNER="tezos"
```

As you notice I added the entry `OWNER=tezos` at the end of the rule. This user should be the same user using `octez-client list connected ledger`.

IMHO, this solution is better from a security point of view than adding the user to the root group

Answer (score 0):

Running `tezos-client list connected ledgers` as root connects to the ledger in order to import private key. But, still cannot find it under user.

Comment: Same situation. `list connected ledgers` only works when running `tezos-client` as root. What's the fix to allow regular user to see ledger?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add the user `tezos` to the group `plugdev` with:

> `sudo adduser tezos plugdev`

Log out and log in again and run:

> `tezos-client list connected ledgers`

Now your ledger should be displayed in the list.

Please note, that I also have installed `Kiln` and this might have modified some configuration that I am not aware of.

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04.